# Textbox that is added dynamically to table is behaving like readonly field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with row expand option. On row expand adding one more table row with cell and appending textbox to the same cell using jquery. This is working fine, but textbox that is added dynamically is behaving like readonly field. Please let me know the solution for the same.

```
<table>
  <tr><td> href field here</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

on click of href field adding row with one cell and textbox in it

```
<tr><td colspan=3 id="test-cell"></td></tr>
```

After appending this to table appending textbox to cell with id "test-cell"

```
$('#test-cell').append('<input type="text" size="10" value="abd" id="test-input" />');
```

Finally table becomes

```
<table>
  <tr><td> href field here</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan=3 id="test-cell"><input type="text" size="10" value="abd" id="test-input" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Tested same code in Chrome, FF, IE 11.

Code that I am using for the same (I extracted this code and replaced generic variable with hard code)

```
var table = $('#C1tbl');
var selectedRow = table.find('tbody>tr.grid-row:eq(2)');
var expandRow = $('<tr class="ag-row-expand"><td colspan="3" id="test-cell"></td></tr>');
expandRow.attr('id', Util.getNextComponentId());
selectedRow.after(expandRow);
var expandCol = expandRow.find('>td');
expandCol.html('<input type="text" size="10" value="abd" id="test-input" />');
```

After this my web page is not allowing to edit the text.

Comment: would be much more easy if you included your code that you're trying to do this with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my mistake only. Table has keydown event to havigate across the rows using navigation keys where function is calling event.preventDefault for all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use $('#test-cell').after().html('< input type="text" size="10"  id="test-input" />')

Comment: Both are same as after also returns same cell reference. If I execute (above code that I  mentioned) as stand alone then it is working fine. But as web page it is not working.